# How do I move a sprite in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sprite

I'm working in Objective-C for a Mac cocoa application. It's a pretty simple question, but I can't find an answer. I just want to move a sprite across the screen, like in a Snake game. Do I need to use NSTimer or NSAnimation, and how would I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use Core Animation.  It provides a unified way to move and animate visual elements on the screen.
If you plan to create a simple game, "Cocoa with Love" has a nice "Asteroid" example:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html

Another game-related Core Animation project is Apple's Geek Game Board:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually it depends on how you imagined your application, there's a lot of way to make things move. If you do not need anything complex or particularly efficient you may just access and modify the NSView frame property. Otherwise you should consider use Core Animation or OpenGL. 
[Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[OpenGL Programming Guide for MacOSX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html)